# asp.net out of memory when filename in cyrillic

Tags: asp.net, image, exception

I have a site, where the user can upload an image.
I save the image under different name into the user's folder (the new file name is random)

Right after I save it, I want to open it.
The problem is, if the ORIGINAL name is in cyrillic or greek alphabet, I got out of memory exception when trying to open it (even if the new name is in latin).
The image is usually small, and even if I take the image, rename it with latin alphabet and upload it, it is alright, so the problem is in the cyrillic characters, thought.

```
//I save the image here under new name
try
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(nazevSouboru), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        //nazevSouboru is the new name, I tried open it directly from the file and from stream, the result is the same
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);//.FromFile(Server.MapPath(nazevSouboru));
        if (img != null)
        {
            //do something with the image
        }

        afuImportImage.Dispose();
        img.Dispose();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //out of memory exception
}
```

I heard the out of memory is used for more exceptions, for example when the imgae is not in correct format.
But I can open the images in any application and the whole think actually WORKS when I rename the file name before uploading.!

The sample images with names in cyrillic or greek alphabet are here:
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R94kL.jpg)
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYjf6.png)

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename)
   at BCConline.Controls.Modals.afuImportImage_UploadComplete(Object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Petr\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BCConline\BCConline\Controls\Modals.ascx.cs:line 91